# how to create PPPoE connection and use it with vb2010 code

Tags: pppoe

I need to create PPPoE Connection with username and password and connect it or disconnect or delete it with `VB 2010` code

thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `radsial` to do that.

See this [command](http://ss64.com/nt/rasdial.html) and [this](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/RasDial.shtml) site may have relavent code

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you but i need code to create my own broadband connection will fit my project i work on it